# Building Flex project with Ant. "The class not found in jar file: mxmlc.jar"

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex3, flash-builder

We've been tirelessly working on trying to catch up on our deployment that was due on Tuesday, so now that we have reached a point of deploying our application, Ant seems to be having difficulties with the mxmlc.jar.

We've tried searching most of this morning on what is going on, but have come up empty. Most of the questions i've asked on here, have an answer that works, so here I am once again.

When trying to run our Ant file I get a these error messages:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\brp\script\build.xml:122: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\workspace\brp\script\build.xml:99: The class not found in jar file: mxmlc.jar
```

The resulting lines of code from that are:

```
<target name="mxml_compile">
        <mxmlc file="${flex.src.dir}/${proj.name}.mxml"
            keep-generated-actionscript="false"
            output="${build.dir}/${proj.name}.swf">
            <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
            <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" />
        </mxmlc>
```

with line 122 being the call to mxml_compile.

The development environment is

- Eclipse Indigo SR2
- Flash Builder 4.6 Plugin
- Flex Compiler is set to SDK 4.6 and Use Flex 3 compatibility mode checked.

We usually do a deployment every two weeks, and nothing other than some java side functionality and quite a few UI changes have been made. We are at a loss as far as where to go from here.

I've tried copying the flexTasks.jar from the sdk file to the source directory that ant is using, as I did find a post somewhere that said that could solve the problem, however it didn't change a thing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just dug around a bit in the flexTasks source code and found that the location of the Flex SDK is referenced through `getProject().getProperty("FLEX_HOME")` and the location of 'mxmlc.jar' is derived from that. So something seems to be wrong with the framework linkage in your project.

Comment: What should the FLEX_HOME be set to? And is this something we should set in the system variables like JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @CodingGuy yah this should be set as a system variable if all else is true, generally FLEX_HOME should be the root of the SDK you're using as in C:\CleanFS\SDKs\flex\3.4.0.9271 <- that location being the root of where I extracted the SDK zip.

Comment: @shaunhusain Ok, so I hard code that into my Ant build.xml as
     <property name="FLEX_HOME" location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0" />

I have both the 3.6.0 and 4.6.0 sdks, everything has been built with 4.6.0, so that is why it is coded as such. When I run the build file with this I get the "Class not found in jar: mxmlc.jar" if I switch the 4.6.0 to 3.6.0, thinking that I am using Flex 3 compatibility mode, I get a different error: mxmlc task failed.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the error and I realized that it was because of two mistakes.
1. My project sdk was 4.6.0, but my flex.properties was referring 4.1.0. I changed the sdk in flex.properties to 4.6.0

1. I had copied flextasks.jar from 4.1.0/ant directory to my project home/lib. I replaced it with the jar from 4.6.0/ant directory. 
   And then the problem got resolved